# How to find the center of a circle with two known tangent lines?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I am trying to develop a geometry-editor and could not solve the following problem.

I have two lines with known equations (y=mx+c) intersecting at a known point P. I want to place a circle with a known radius R, so that the two lines form tangents to the circle. How do I calculate the center coordinates of the circle?

Any help would be appreciated!

See the attached image.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: My recommendation is to define lines with $(a,b,c)$ coefficients such that the equation of the line is $$ax + by + c =0$$ this will allow you to define _all_ possible lines on the plane, including the $x=c$ line.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/797891/3301

Comment: Also note that the circle that has points _P_ and _C_ in its diameters also goes through the tangent points https://i.imgur.com/QZOw2vt.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can translate each line perpendicular to itself by $r$.  These two translated lines will be each $r$ away from one of the original lines and thus a circle centered on a point on the translated line will be tangent to the original line.  The intersection of the two translated lines will be the center of a circle tangent to both lines.

Note that you can translate each line two different ways, giving four possible centers for the circle. All four work!

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave it for you to formalize everything algebraically, but there is a classical construction to solve this problem.

Note that the line $CI_1$ is perpendicular to the first tangent, and so is the line $CI_2$ to the second one. These intersect at a single point (namely, $C$). Thus, given the two lines, in order to find *a* center of *a* circle tangent to both (there are infinitely many, exactly four of each given radius - one on each side of the intersection point), you just need to pick two tangency points, draw perpendiculars to both relative to the tangent lines, and take their intersection.

In order to pick the tangency points you want to draw the perpendiculars from, you can use the tangent of the angle in between them to solve for the distance.